# C# Convert long value to specific date time (timezone dont matter)

Tags: c#

I have a long digit `1451656856` and I was expected to convert it to value `2016-01-01 14:00:56.000`

I tried adding it as milliseconds to epoch value (1-1-1970) but I can't produce the result and instead return `17/01/1970 7:14:16 PM`

[image: S]

May I know how will I be able to convert that kind of long digit to my expected value as adding it as milliseconds to epoch don't work.

Comment: That number is way too small to represent 46 years in milliseconds. A single day has 86400000ms. Probably it's just seconds. So just do `epoch.AddSeconds(a)`

Comment: Please consider writing an answer and accepting it or deleting the question if you don't think this will be useful for others. As is - this question will keep dangling around, which is not desirable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quoting @[derpischer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776927/derpirscher)'s comment in the question

That number is way too small to represent 46 years in milliseconds. A single day has 86400000ms. Probably it's just seconds. So just do `epoch.AddSeconds(a)`

This actually worked.